# how to access Mi-fare ultralight 1k tag

Tags: nfc, mifare

Please help me how to access Mi-fare ultralight 1k tag.

I tried the commands

```
ff 82 00 01 06 ff ff ff ff ff ff and ff 82 00 01 06 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
```

which load successfully on reader.

But When I try command

```
ff 88 00 01 60 00
```

which is use to authentication with tag

status words **63 00 (operation failed)**

Log is listed below

```
[ACS ACR122 0] : Running script
[1] > ff 82 00 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
< 90 00
[2] > ff 88 00 01 60 00
< 63 00
[ACS ACR122 0] : Running script
[1] > ff 82 00 01 06 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
< 90 00
[2] > ff 88 00 01 60 00
< 63 00
```

---

ATR of MIFARE 1K tag Which is I am using

```
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
```

Below give script which is came with ACR122U reader for MIFARE 1K tag.
Which is also unsuccessful

Demo script for MIFARE 1K card and ACR122U PC/SC reader

(c) 2008, Advanced Card Systems Ltd.

```
[1] Load (Mifare Default) key in reader (key location 0)
FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF (9000)

; [2] Authenticate sector 0, Block 0 with key at location 0
FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 60 00 (9000)

; [3] Read the full 16 bytes from Sector 0, Block 1
FF B0 00 01 10 [xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx] (9000)

; [4] Update the 16 bytes in Sector 0, block 1
FF D6 00 01 10 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F (9000)

; [5] Read the full 16 bytes from Sector 0, Block 1 again
FF B0 00 01 10 [xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx] (9000)

; [6] Authenticate sector 1, Block 5 with key at location 0
FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 05 60 00 (9000)

; [7] Store a value "1" into block 5
FF D7 00 05 05 00 00 00 00 01 (9000)

; [8] Read the value block 5
FF B1 00 05 04 [xx xx xx xx] (9000)

; [9] Copy the value from value block 5 to value block 6
FF D7 00 05 02 03 06 (9000)

; [10] Read the value block 6
FF B1 00 06 04 [xx xx xx xx] (9000)

; [11] Increment the value block 5 by "5"
FF D7 00 05 05 01 00 00 00 05 (9000)

; [12] Read the value block 5
FF B1 00 05 04 [xx xx xx xx] (9000)
```

Comment: There is no MIFARE Ultralight 1K. Perhaps you mean MIFARE Classic 1K?

Comment: I hope this answer can help you --> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881962/authentication-error-for-mifare-card-6982security-status-not-satisfied/16791350#16791350][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881962/authentication-error-for-mifare-card-6982security-status-not-satisfied/16791350#16791350

Answer (score 2):

The card seems to me like MIFARE Classic 1K.

I think you have mistake in the key number that you are tying to authenticate with. Try this:

```
ff 82 00 01 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF  //Set key with on slot 1
ff 88 00 01 60 01                 //Auth with key from slot 1 to block 1
```

I hope this will help.