# authentication error for mifare card “6982:Security status not satisfied”

Tags: authentication, command, smartcard, mifare, apdu

I know this question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908239/authentication-error-for-mifare-card-6982security-status-not-satisfied). But the answers are useless for me.

I have pc/sc reader and contactless card(mifare card), I can connect to the card and also I can execute the `getdate` command successfully. However, when I want to authenticate I see this error:

> "6982:Security status not satisfied"

I've tried these 4 different commands for authentication but I get the same error for all of them.

```
FF 88 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF 88 00 00 60 12
FF 88 00 00 05 01 00 12 60 00
FF 88 00 00 60 00
```

How can I authenticate to this card ?

Answer (score 1):

The GENERAL AUTHENTICATE instruction performs a Mifare Classic authentication (CRYPTO1).
The application must provide the index of the key to be used; this key must have been loaded into
the reader through a previous LOAD KEY instruction.

**Do not invoke this function if the currently activated PICC/VICC is not a Mifare Classic!**

> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00  blockNo  keyLocation  keyIndex

Where

blockNo = is the address on the card, where we try to be authenticated.

keyLocation  =

- h60 for authentication using a CRYPTO1 “A” key (standard PC/SC-defined value)
- h61 for authentication using a CRYPTO1 “B” key (standard PC/SC-defined value)

keyIndex = key index in the reader where you have load the key(posible value from 0x00 to 0x1f)

Comment: am using your apdu command but it return 1C what is the meaning of it.

Comment: Return code of any command is 2 byte long,like 0x9000 for success. but "1C" not possible. btw which reader you are using?

Comment: @vikky Do you mind sharing your suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548209/69-82security-condition-not-satisfied-adpu-resposne-with-android-nfc